# Intellij reports "Installed module matplotlib" and "No module named matplotlib" at the same time

Tags: python, intellij-idea

From within Intellij I right clicked on the module `matplotlib` and invoked the "Install module"

[image]

After about thirty seconds of downloading/installing/ and ***Generating skeletons for new module ..*** a popup came in the bottom right statusbar saying

**Installed module matplotlib** .

I was not quick enough to get a screenshot of it unfortunately.

But then at the same time in the bottom *left* of the statusbar the `No module named matplotlib` showed: the contradictory messages were present *at the same time* .

[image]

So then - what gives here: is there some magical set of operations to get Intellij python to recognize the newly installed module?

Btw from the *command line* the following does now work:

```
  echo "import matplotlib" | python
```

So the installation did apparently "take".  But intellij does not pick it up.

**Update**  I'm seeing this behavior across a number of modules:  here's `statsmodels` behaving the same way:

[image]

This reduces the usability of Intellij since the methods of those libraries are not available for inspection.